# Capacitor filesystem write permission error in android 13

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I used the capacitor filesystem to download image, for Android 12 and below there were no problems, but permission problems appeared on Android 13 target API 33. I use capacitor 4

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
```

```
await Filesystem.writeFile({
     path: fileName + '.jpeg',
     data: base64Data,
     directory: Directory.Documents
});
```

Error: Missing the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with Cordova:

Rather than doing this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" android:minSdkVersion="33" />
```

I flipped it around (not sure if it makes a difference):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Then, when calling the filesystem in my application, I used a combination of `@awesome-cordova-plugins/device` and `@awesome-cordova-plugins/android-permissions` to check for the correct permissions.

For example, this method is called before trying to access audio storage:

```
public async requestAccessToAudioStorage(): Promise<boolean> {
    let response: AndroidPermissionResponse;
    if (Number(this.device.sdkVersion) >= 33) {
        response = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO);
    } else {
        response = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    return response.hasPermission;
}
```

I know it is not a 1:1 solution, but hopefully this helps.